# Xiaomi router 4A cant connect to hotel network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I'm at dominican republic, and for my room I wanted to connect a xiaomi 4A to expand the coverage since the router is outside, but for a reason at the miWifi setup, this country doesnt exist, and when I try to connect with wifi (As a wifi-repeater) It manages to create both 2.4 and 5ghz bands with the name and password I give it, but then I can't access it, nor connect to it. My hotel network password is a standar wifi password, but when connecting, you need to access with your room, name, gmail, etc, so maybe this is interfeering? Any ideas would help! Thanks.

Comment: I doubt your router can answer the script questions for access.

Comment: You might try to use a PC as a wireless hotspot, https://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot

Comment: Specifying more, I want to use quest air, and the laptop itself lags to create the hotspot and support the 200mb stream, and for a reason on the hotel router both connected, the dont recognize each other